# Trying to add a dropdown field to my refinerycms engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm trying to add a dropdown field to an already existing engine that I created. I followed this guide http://refinerycms.com/guides/multiple-resources-in-an-extension and when i ran the command `rails g refinery:engine categories name:string --extension group_classes`

I then tried running `bundle install` and then `rails generate refinery:group_classes` and then i got this error:
`rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the version number 1`

I looked at the migrations in the vender/extensions/group_classes/db/migrate folder and they both had the prefix of 1. I changed the categories prefix to 2 and reran everything and it worked but then when i tried running `rake db:seed`, I get this error:
`rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Refinery::GroupClasses::Engine`

Full stack trace:

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Refinery::GroupClasses::Engine
/var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT/db/seeds.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT/refinerycms/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/var/www/vhosts/tomstestsite.us/PersonalTrainingKT/refinerycms/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:309:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

What would cause this?

Answer (score 1):

try use again without  `--extension group_classes` OR you try to restart your server?

Comment: If i try it without the --extension piece it would just create an engine for categories which would be separate from group_classes. And yes i've tried restarting my server.

Comment: may be seed.rb have a bad syntax?

Comment: which version you're using? if < 2.0.6 then you must update it, because https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/issues/1885

Comment: I was using a version less than 2.0.6. Let me upgrade and try it again and let you know if i'm still having the same issues.